# Error using Unobserved State Space- ucm() in R

Tags: r, time-series, state-space

I am using `ucm()` function of package `rucm` in R. I am trying to predict sales where units is dependent variable and month,day,temperature are independent variables. While running code I am getting following error

```
Code:

UCM_test_reg<-ucm(units~month+day,train_data, irregular = TRUE, level = TRUE,season = TRUE,season.length = 7) 

Error :

Error in modelH$Q[find.level - length(indep.var), find.level - length(indep.var),  : 
subscript out of bounds
```

Month and day are categorical variables and temperature is continuous.Is it because of using categorical variable?
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that delivers the same error as above. Will increase your chances of getting an answer. Without code we can only take guesses...

Answer (score 0):

Please install the package rucm from github. This was a bug [here](https://github.com/kaushikrch/rucm/issues/1)